# I don't understand why I'm getting down votes on my question. I am new here please help

Tags: support, specific-question

I have a question about my Chemistry Stack Exchange post: [Explanation of pi bonding and synergic bonding in coordination compounds using MOT](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70261/explanation-of-pi-bonding-and-synergic-bonding-in-coordination-compounds-using-m)

I am new to this place. I couldn't understand what is wrong with my question that i am getting negative votes. Please help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At this time, your question has three close votes as "too broad". This is probably because you've asked about more than one topic (*pi bonding in coordination compounds* and *synergic bonds*), and possibly also because either one of these topics by itself may require an extremely long answer.

First, I would ask about pi bonds and synergic bonds in separate questions.

Second, I would ask about *specific aspects* of each of the types of bonds, that you are confused about, or would like to learn more about.

More generally, read through the [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and browse the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) for the site -- they both have a lot of information on the site policies and expectations.